# Do we need community promotion ads?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, advertising

Other sites have this feature and it seems quite popular.

Some examples: [physics](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6388/community-promotion-ads-2015), [math](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6388/community-promotion-ads-2015), [unix](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3311/community-promotion-ads-2015), [security](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1694/community-promotion-ads-2015).

I think, it would be a wonderful way to promote other SE sites, to further extend the SE network.

Comment: [Related blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/community-promotion-ads/)

Answer (score 46):

Why we *don't* have community promotion ads has already been [answered over on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227265/why-no-community-promotion-ads-for-stack-overflow):

> The "Community Promotion Ads" were actually born out of the "Open Source" initiative started on Stack Overflow. So Stack Overflow had the community-driven ads first.
>
> It was the early success and overall good will of the Open Source project that made us think that, perhaps, *other* communities would appreciate having this feature, too. So the two programs are essentially one and the same, except that the other sites don't have the same sense-of-purpose for those ads as Stack Overflow (I wish they ***did,*** actually… but we're not there, yet).
>
> **So why doesn't Stack Overflow just include general Community Promotion Ads in the mix?**
>
> The Open Source advertising initiative is such a successful program. We have allocated, essentially, a block of "free" advertising to this effort. I'd hate to lose that focus by opening that space up to a bunch of *other* things people might like to advertise. I can appreciate that you want to promote other sites and a plethora of other things here. But there are so many open source project needing our help. I'd hate to lose that focus by diluting that space with other promotions.

**TL;DR** Community Promotion Ads would dilute the Open Source Ads that Stack Overflow is more focused on presenting.